# Pandas dataframe query with variables

Tags: python, filter

```
df.query('ZIP_(3-DIGIT) < 100')
```

returns:

> ValueError: "ZIP_" is not a supported function

```
df.query('@ZIP_(3-DIGIT) < 100')
```

returns:

> ValueError: "__pd_eval_local_ZIP_" is not a supported function

`ZIP_(3-DIGIT)` is int64

I can use `df[df['ZIP_(3-DIGIT)'] < 100]` to achieve the desired result, but I would like to learn what I was doing wrong.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ZIP_(3-DIGIT)': np.arange(0,10000)})
```

Comment: 200k rows by 25 columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the parentheses and hyphen in your column name.

Any column that you couldn't access with `df` + <kbd>tab</kbd> also can't be parsed by `.query`.  I don't know pandas internals and can't answer your question beyond that level of depth.

For example if you had:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ZIP_3DIGIT': np.arange(0,10000)})
```

You could do:

```
print(df.ZIP_3DIGIT.head(3))
0    0
1    1
2    2
Name: ZIP_3DIGIT, dtype: int32
```

Now try this with your current name and things will not work.

So to use query, use `rename` and method chain `query` to that:

```
df.rename(columns={'ZIP_(3-DIGIT)' : 'ZIP_3DIGIT'}).query('ZIP_3DIGIT < 100')
```